# Reconocimiento facial para el control de datos

Tags: python, funciones, condiciones, print, procesamiento-de-texto

```
    if result[1] < 70: 
        cv2.putText(frame,'{}'.format(imagePaths[result[0 ]]),(x,y-25),2,1.1,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

        cara= format(imagePaths[result[0 ]])
        nombrecara=str(cara)
        cararesult=(result[1] < 70)
        contador= 1
        

        
        if cararesult is True:
          print(nombrecara+  "   DETECTADO")
          
          
          
          

      
        

    else:
        cv2.putText(frame,'Desconocido',(x,y-20),2,0.8,(0,0,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    
        return frame
```

Como se puede apreciar en el codigo en la parte de if cararesult is True me imprime a quien esta detectando en la consola, pero el problema es que se imprimi sin fin de veces debido a los fotogramas que va leyendo en el video stream, quisiera saber alguna manera para hacer que me envie el nombre de (persona x) cada determinado tiempo y solo una vez, igual cuando detecte a mas personas haga lo mismo , solo la muestre una vez, intente con time.sleep pero detiene el codigo y yo quisiera que siguiera corriendo el programa mientras hace lo anterior.

Quisiera alguna ayuda o alguna forma para que se puediera realizar cierta accion

Comment: Puedes utilizar una variable para almacenar el tiempo pasado desde la última vez que lo imprimió, y solo imprimir nuevamente si ha pasado X tiempo o si ha detectado alguna otra cosa

Comment: si , pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo